# helm upgrade: Error: could not find a ready tiller pod

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, amazon-eks

I'm new to EKS, Helm, and tiller. I am looking into why our build is breaking for our cluster deployment. I'm getting the error  `Error: could not find a ready tiller pod` when running helm upgrade. I see a lot of threads with this problem, but I want to have a better understanding of what's happening before I put in a PR.

There was a thread to add `--upgrade` and `--wait` flags to the helm init command. That didn't seem to do the trick. It looks like we also are using the `--client-only` flag which is making me think it is the culprit. However, that flag was added 2 years ago so I don't understand why it would be breaking now.

```
helm init --upgrade --wait --stable-repo-url=https://charts.helm.sh/stable --client-only --kubeconfig ./cluster_config

echo "Helm repo update"
helm repo update --kubeconfig ./cluster_config

echo "helm upgrade"
helm upgrade --install aws-efs-csi-driver https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-efs-csi-driver/releases/download/v0.3.0/helm-chart.tgz --force --kubeconfig ./cluster_config
```

Update: added `helm version --tls`

```
13:27:00  [docker] [deploy-terraform] [terraform apply] null_resource.setup_cluster (local-exec): Helm Version
apply] null_resource.setup_cluster (local-exec): Client: &version.Version{SemVer:"v2.16.9", GitCommit:"8ad7037828e5a0fca1009dabe290130da6368e39", GitTreeState:"clean"}
13:27:05  [docker] [deploy-terraform] [terraform apply] null_resource.setup_cluster (local-exec): Error: Get "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/pods?labelSelector=app%3Dhelm%2Cname%3Dtiller": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connect: connection refused
```

****Solution****
Upgrade to Helm v3 :-/

Comment: Which version of Helm are you using? v2 and v3 are significantly different from an architecture perspective.

Comment: Anything that mentions "Tiller" is the obsolete Helm v2; it's been [out of support](https://helm.sh/blog/helm-2-becomes-unsupported/) and unmaintained for over a year and a half at this point.  Can you update your system to use Helm v3 instead?

Comment: @DavidMaze I'll look into upgrading. There will be a lot of changes so I'm going to wait on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you specify the `--client-only` flag, the `tiller` server is never started in the cluster. Hence your problem. You can remove the flag and it should work.

See [the docs](https://v2.helm.sh/docs/helm/#options-16) for more details.

Update: Based on the output of `helm version --tls` and the discussion in comments, we can see that the tiller service is not working and pods are stuck in `IMAGE_PULL_BACKOFF`. Fixing that will fix this issue.

The tiller pods can no longer pull images since the upstream registry has been decommissioned. The image name can be changed to `omio/gcr.io.kubernetes-helm.tiller:v2.16.1`. This is a working registry for `helm v2`.

Comment: I removed client only flag. Now I'm getting `Error: tiller was not found. polling deadline exceeded`

Comment: Try running `helm version`, do you see the same error? Also try the `--tls` flag with this command. It might be a certificate issue.

Comment: add --tls to `helm version`?

Comment: In update section... it did fail.

Comment: what is the output of `helm version` and `helm version --tls`?

Comment: The output is in the update section of my question

Comment: If you have access to the k8s server, can you check if you have any pods running with the labels as the error reports?
`kubectl get pods -n kube-system -lapp=helm,name=tiller`

Comment: I have two tiller-deploy pods with those labels. Both in failed state // image back off from last month.

Comment: Ah! That' why it isn't working. Can you check if the image name in the pod is correct? One way to do this is by running `docker pull <IMAGE_NAME>` on your host, and seeing if the image can be pulled.

Comment: docker pull gcr.io/kubernetes-helm/tiller:v2.16.9
Error response from daemon: Head "https://gcr.io/v2/kubernetes-helm/tiller/manifests/v2.16.9": unknown: Project 'project:kubernetes-helm' not found or deleted.

Comment: Oh, yes. That's because the `helm v2` project was decommissioned and the registry no longer holds the image that you can use :) This is a way for them to force you to upgrade to v3. You can try to change the image name with `kubectl edit -nkube-system <PODNAME>` and add this image name instead `omio/gcr.io.kubernetes-helm.tiller:v2.16.1`. This is known to work.

Comment: I think it's time to upgrade to v3, lol. Thanks for the help man!